Collisional Association Cross-section
Suppose I have a free proton and a free hydrogen atom that collide. How would I go about determining the cross-section for the collision to result in an $H_2^+$ molecule in a particular vibrational state and the ground rotational state? Are there any references that have already calculated such a cross-section?
